# Haskell-filter first element

Tags: haskell

I want to remove the first element that does not have a certain property.
For example, if my property is defined as...

```
greaterOne :: Num a=>Ord a=>a->Bool
greaterOne x = x > 1
```

Then the function `filterFirst` should give me this...

```
filterFirst greaterOne [5,-6,-7,9,10]
>> [5,-7,9,10]  //removes first element that is not greater than one
```

This is my attempt...

```
filterFirst :: (a->Bool)->[a]->[a]
filterFirst p [] = []
filterFirst p (x:y:xs)
    |p x = filterFirst p xs
    |otherwise = y:xs
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: You probably want something like `f p xs = let (as, (b:bs)) = span p xs in as ++ bs`, possibly with some logic to handle the cases where no element matches the predicate and where the last element is the first to match.

Comment: `filterFirst p (x:xs) = if p x then x : filterFirst p xs else xs`

Comment: @user2407038, why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: @user2407038 I would pick that as best answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Walk through what your attempt does: `[]` is sent to `[]` (this is correct). With a list with at least two elements (`x:y:xs`), your function tests `x`, *throws out `x` and `y`* and keeps filtering if the test *passes* (definitely not what you want), and throws out `x` and stops if the test fails (this is correct). A list with a single element errors out, as will many other lists with an odd number of elements (this is both bad and a clue to the correct answer).

Let's walk through a correct implementation a step at a time. As you wrote, we want `filterFirst` to take a predicate on `a` and a list of `a` and return another list of `a`:

```
filterFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

The predicate type `a -> Bool` can't be broken down, but `[a]` can: there can be empty lists `[]` and nonempty lists `x:xs`, and there should be a case for each:

```
filterFirst p []     = ...
filterFirst p (x:xs) = ...
```

In the "base case" `[]`, there's nothing left to filter, so we want this to be `[]`, which is what you've written. Since `p` isn't used here, you could replace `p` in this case with `_`:

```
filterFirst _ [] = []
```

but you don't have to.

What we want to do with `x:xs` depends on the value of `p x`.  If `p x` holds, we want a list that starts with `x`. The tail of this list should be `xs`, but with the first failing element removed.  If `p x` fails, we want to throw out `x` (the first failing element) and keep `xs` (the list after the first failing element).  So:

```
filterFirst p (x:xs)
    | p x       = x:filterFirst p xs
    | otherwise = xs
```

And that covers all the possibilities, so we're done!

**EDIT** per dfeuer's comment.

Comment: Great answer, but I would write "If `p x` holds" rather than "If `p x == True`". A lot of people get confused and write funny-looking code using `==` to test `Bool` values.

Answer (score 5):

You can abuse `deleteBy` for this.

```
> deleteBy (>) 1 [5, -6, -7, 9, 10]
[5,-7,9,10]
```

...and more generally:

```
filterFirst p = deleteBy (const p) undefined
```