# Haskell abbreviating multiple parameters to a single variable

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, currying

So I have a function which *has to* have a certain type. My implementation is similar to the following:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
f t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
    = filterFirst checkFunc p
    where
        p = findAll [1..9]
        checkFunc = validate t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
```

Now is there any way I could abbreviate the t values to either *change validate and then rearrange f* or something similar the following:

```
f :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int
f ts
    = filterFirst checkFunc p
    where
        p = findAll [1..9]
        checkFunc = validate ts
```

A way to make this look cleaner would be amazing.

**Edit:** More Detail

```
validate :: Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [Int] -> Bool
validate t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 is =
    [t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9] == sums is

-- Calculates sums from specific indexes in list
sums :: [Int] -> [Int]

-- from https://stackoverflow.com/a/28904773/1218369
filterFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]

-- Find all possible permutations
findAll :: [a] -> [[a]]
-- Basically Data.List (permutations)
```

The problem is f must have the values passed as parameters. I was looking and even some function that takes any number of parameters and produces a list would be helpful but I can't seem to find any module with such function.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you want to simplify.

Comment: The isomorphism you want between `Int -> ... Int -> Int` and `(Int, ..., Int) -> Int` isn't going to be any prettier than what you are doing now. Somewhere along the line, a bad design decision lead to you needing `f` to have that type.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. I didn't make the design decision for `f` but have to work with it. Was just hoping there was a way to select all the arguments like in other languages or formulate a function using validate which I could use to make a definition for f without specifying the arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's rewrite this in a form that looks closer to composing a partial application of `filterFirst` with a function that actually consumes the `t` values:

```
f t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 = let cf = validate t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9
                               in (flip filterFirst) (findAll [1..9]) cf
```

http://pointfree.io then tells us that the above is equivalent to

```
f = ((((((((flip filterFirst (findAll [1..9]) .) .) .) .) .) .) .) .) . validate
```

The multiple layers of composition allows us to avoid repeating the `t` names in the definition.

I wouldn't, however, claim this is an improvement over your explicit version.