# Remove first element that fulfills predicate (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I want to make a function that removes the first element that fulfills the predicate given in the second argument. Something like this:

```
removeFirst "abab" (< 'b')  = "bab"
removeFirst "abab" (== 'b') = "aab"
removeFirst "abab" (> 'b')  = "abab"
removeFirst [1,2,3,4] even  = [1,3,4]
```

I wanted to do it by recursively, and came up with this:

```
removeFirst :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
removeFirst [] _ = []
rremoveFirst (x:xs) p = if p x then x : removeFirst xs p else removeFirst xs p
```

(Inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28890617/haskell-filter-first-element/28904773) question)
But I get a type-error, like this:

```
Couldn't match type ‘a’ with ‘Bool’
  Expected: [Bool]
    Actual: [a]
  ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      removeFirst :: forall a. [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
```

or this:

```
ghci> removeFirst [1,2,3,4] even

<interactive>:25:1: error:
    * Variable not in scope: removeFirst :: [a0] -> (a1 -> Bool) -> t
    * Perhaps you meant `rem' (imported from Prelude)
```

I know this is a relatively simple thing to program, I am just not familiar enough with Haskell yet. How can I do this "Haskell-style" (in one line)?

Comment: Could not reproduce (even after fixing the typo `rremoveFirst` -> `removeFirst`). Are you sure you've copied the code you're trying out *exactly*? In particular, does your original code have `p x` instead of `x` in the `then` branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not one line, but it works.

```
 removeFirst :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
 removeFirst (x:xs) pred
   | pred x    = xs
   | otherwise = x : removeFirst xs pred
```

For a one-liner, I imagine you'd want to use `foldl` to walk across the list from the left.

**EDIT**

This solution uses guards, it first checks to see if the first element of the list passed in satisfies the predicate, and if not, it prepends it to the list and recursively checks the tail of the passed in list.

Comment: Please explain your answer and explain the problems encountered in the question.

Comment: The OP didn't ask for an explanation, just a solution.

Comment: You could replace `pred x == True` by just `pred x`. That's already a boolean value.

Comment: @jpmarinier Noted.

Answer (score 4):

Before doing it "in style", why not first simply *do* it, so it *works*. This is how we learn.

"`Variable not in scope: removeFirst ...`" simply means you haven't defined the function named `removeFirst`.

So it seems you first tried to define it (and the error you show does *not* go with the code you show), then you got errors so it didn't get defined, and then you tried calling it and got the error saying it's not defined yet, naturally.

So, save your program in a source file, then load that file in GHCi. Then if you get any errors please copy-paste the *full* code from your file into your question (do *not* re-type it by hand). Also please specify what is it you do when you get the error messages, *precisely*. And be sure to include the error messages in full by copy-pasting them as well.

*Then* the logic of your code can be addressed.

---

Since others have posted working code, here's how I'd code this as a one-liner of sorts:

```
remFirst :: [a] -> (a -> Bool) -> [a]
remFirst xs p = foldr g z xs xs
  where
  g x r ~(_:tl)      -- "r" for recursive result
     | p x           -- we've found it, then
       = tl          -- just return the tail
     | otherwise
       = x : r tl    -- keep x and continue
  z _  = []          -- none were found
```

Shortened, it becomes

```
remFirst xs p = 
  foldr (\x r ~(_:tl) -> if p x then tl else x : r tl)
        (const []) xs xs
```

Comment: (posting an answer as an answer and not as a comment.)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am trying to learn as I go, but I don't learn my just knowing the theory and logic behind, I learn by doing. So I am trying to do 'simple' task and then learn as I go. 
I do appreciate the constructive feedback, I wont re-type code in stack by hand.

Comment: as I said in the answer, the error message does not correspond with the code you show, so you must have loaded some other code. have you loaded it from file, or by typing at the prompt? (you also have a typo in one of the lines, `rremoveFirst...` FYI).

Comment: the SO way is, post a specific code, its test call and error messages, as is, and get answers. :) it's not a forum where you get clues and work out issues on your own. the Q&A entries are supposed to be consistent, to tell a specific, if very short and focused, story. not be a comment on something that's happening somewhere else. :) happy trails. :)

Comment: @Mampenda BTW this wasn't criticism at all, just some suggestions so that the future cooperation could be more productive for all of us here.

Answer (score 1):

Using manual recursion does not lead to a one-liner solution, so let's try using some pre-built recursion scheme from the library.

Function [`scanl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:scanl) looks handy. It produces a succession of *states*, one state per input item.

Testing under the `ghci` interpreter:

```
$ ghci
 λ> 
 λ> p = (=='b')
 λ> 
 λ> xs = "ababcdab"
 λ> ss = tail $ scanl (\(s,n) x -> if (p x) then (x,n+1) else (x,n)) (undefined,0)  xs
 λ> 
 λ> ss
 [('a',0),('b',1),('a',1),('b',2),('c',2),('d',2),('a',2),('b',3)]
 λ>
```

At that point, it is easy to spot and get rid of the one unwanted element, thru some simple data massaging:

```
 λ> 
 λ> filter (\(x,n) -> (n /= 1) || (not $ p x))  ss 
 [('a',0),('a',1),('b',2),('c',2),('d',2),('a',2),('b',3)]
 λ> 
 λ> map fst $ filter (\(x,n) -> (n /= 1) || (not $ p x))  ss 
 "aabcdab"
 λ>
```

Let's now write our `removeFirst` function. I take the liberty to have the predicate as leftmost argument; this is what all library functions do.

```
removeFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
removeFirst p =
    let
        stepFn = \(s,n) x -> if (p x) then (x,n+1) else (x,n)
        p2     = \(x,n) -> (n /= 1) || (not $ p x)
    in
        map fst . filter p2 . tail . scanl stepFn (undefined,0)
```

If required, this version can be changed into a one-liner solution, just by expanding the values of `stepFn` and `p2` into the last line. Left as an exercise for the reader. It makes for a long line, so it is debatable whether that improves readability.

### Addendum:

Another approach consists in trying to find a library function, similar to [`splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt) but taking a predicate instead of the list position.

So we submit the `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])` type signature into the [Hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org) specialized search engine.

This readily finds the [`break`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:break) library function. It is exactly what we require.

```
 λ> 
 λ> break (=='b') "zqababcdefab"
 ("zqa","babcdefab")
 λ>
```

So we can write our `removeFirst` function like this:

```
removeFirst :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
removeFirst p xs = let  (ys,zs) = break p xs  in  ys ++ (tail zs)
```

The [source code for `break`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/src/GHC-List.html#break) simply uses manual recursion.

Comment: I don't think it is really debatable at all. :) this code is really a bit _too_ unwieldy. it breaks one of the main tenets of good minimal (i.e. efficient) code, by constructing values to be tested later when these results are known in advance. the standard way to implement filter is with foldr; to make a foldr that can stop in the middle we pass it another argument; to give the combining function access to the current tail (a.o.t. only the current head as in foldr) we _pass it another argument_ which is the list itself, (contd.)

Comment: ... [advancing along it by hand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55523947/849891), shifted by one position (possibly; or maybe not; as needed). (some consider this scheme to be ["disgusting"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55522847/implementing-haskells-take-function-using-foldl/55523947#comment97756176_55523947) :) ) this would make it ([an emulation of](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14451312/849891)) a paramorphism. the final code should be short enough too. :)

Comment: I couldn't help it and added to my answer the code which I had in mind. it practically wrote itself, too. :)

Comment: @WillNess yes I see, nicely idiomatic solution. Somewhat akin to the expression of foldl using foldr, if I understand correctly.

Comment: that's `\p -> ((++) . fst <*> tail . snd) . break p`. :)

Comment: @WillNess Yes, a nice thing with Haskell is that with just a tiny little problem, you can display a very large amount of creativity :-)

Comment: or perhaps `\p -> uncurry (++) . (id *** tail) . break p` is better, more minimal, _less_ creative. :)